# Why are IsEqualGUID() and "operator ==" for GUID declared to return int?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com

Windows SDK features [IsEqualGUID()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680575(VS.85).aspx) function and `operator==()` for two GUIDs that return `BOOL` (equivalent to `int`):

```
// Guiddef.h
#ifdef __cplusplus
__inline int IsEqualGUID(REFGUID rguid1, REFGUID rguid2)
{
    return !memcmp(&rguid1, &rguid2, sizeof(GUID));
}
#else   // ! __cplusplus
    #define IsEqualGUID(rguid1, rguid2) (!memcmp(rguid1, rguid2, sizeof(GUID)))
#endif
//also in Guiidef.h
#ifdef __cplusplus
__inline int operator==(REFGUID guidOne, REFGUID guidOther)
{
    return IsEqualGUID(guidOne,guidOther);
}
#endif
```

What's the point in that `int`? I understand that C doesn't have `bool` datatype, but there's an `#ifdef __cplusplus` around, so this code will only be compiled as C++, so `bool` will be supported anyway. Having a negation near `memcmp()` effectively transforms all possible values returned from `memcmp()` into zero and nonzero.

Also there're no user-defined operators in C - only C++ supports them. So the `operator==` would not compile in C code anyway.

Are there any reasons for choosing `int` instead of `bool` here?

Comment: I don't see a reason except consistency with other APIs. What's in the #else?

Comment: @roe: in the `#else` is `#define IsEqualGUID(rguid1, rguid2) (!memcmp(rguid1, rguid2, sizeof(GUID)))` which is the same evil but as a macro.

Comment: +1 A possible answer is here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/12/22/329884.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the Windows API exposes `IsEqualGUID()` as a function returning a `BOOL`. They need to keep a stable interface. `BOOL` and `bool` are different sizes, and the Windows API is designed to be compatible with a variety of languages and compilers. Remember that there are other languages other than C++ that interact with the Windows API.

On C and C++, `IsEqualGUID()` is implemented in terms of `memcmp()`, but `IsEqualGUID()` is also implemented in `ole32.dll`. You can obtain the function from `ole32.dll`:

```
REFGUID guid1 = IID_IUnknown;
REFGUID guid2 = IID_AsyncIUnknown;
typedef BOOL (WINAPI *IsEqualGUIDFuncType)(REFGUID, REFGUID);
HMODULE h = ::LoadLibrary("ole32.dll");
IsEqualGUIDFuncType f = reinterpret_cast<IsEqualGUIDFuncType>
    (::GetProcAddress(h, "IsEqualGUID"));
if(f != NULL)
{
    if(f(guid1, guid2) != 0)
        ::printf("true\n");
    else
        ::printf("false\n");
}
::FreeLibrary(h);
```

So even though it's implemented as an inline function in C++, other languages may use the DLL implementation of `IsEqualGUID()`. The C++ version returns a `BOOL` so it is consistent with the API.

Comment: But that was a "C++" version. Why should C++ interface look like that?

Comment: Because the Windows operating system exposes `IsEqualGUID()` as a function returning an `int` (modified my answer to mention this).

Comment: Em... The implementation is right there in the header file. Who then exposes what? How is Windows itself related to it?

Comment: It just so happens that it's implemented that way in C++. Remember there are other languages other than C++ that interacts with the Windows API.

Comment: But again... That's not "API" - that's some helper function specific to C++. It doesn't need to be language-independent.

Comment: `IsEqualGUID()` is not specific to C++. It can be called from other languages. (like C#:  http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/ole32/IsEqualGUID.html)

Comment: I see now. But that doesn't clarify the situation with operator== anyway.

Comment: The == operator is probably a convenience for C++ developers. It's present only when `__cplusplus` is defined.

Comment: With this "convenience" each time I want to write `const bool sameIds = guid1 == guid2;` I get C4800 warning and now have to write `const bool sameIds = IsEqualGUID( guid1, guid2 ) != 0;` which is soooo convenient that makes the operator == completely useless.

Comment: `const BOOL sameIds = guid1 == guid2;` works without warning. So does `const bool sameIds = (guid1 == guid2) !=0;`. It returns a `BOOL` probably because they want to keep the interface consistent.

Comment: Also, Windows doesn't expose it as a function. In C, you can't take its address., and you can't get it via `GetProcAddress()` either.

Comment: It is most definitely exposed as a function in `ole32.dll` in which you can get via `GetProcAddress(h, "IsEqualGUID")` after loading `ole32.dll` via `HMODULE h = LoadLibrary("ole32.dll")`.

Answer (score 3):

> Are there any reasons for choosing int
>   instead of bool here?

There may be more than one reason:

- consistency of the interface between C and C++ may be desired by the designers
- backwards compatibility: The Windows SDK has been kept (roughly) backwards compatible since the big bang (or immediately afterwards). This ensures that client code will require less effort to port to a new Windows version and that new Windows versions will have more of an applications base when released (old applications that keep working on new Windows with minimal effort).
- using only C language types may be desired for interoperability with C
- the boolean type may not be supported on some platforms - like Windows CE development (I'm not sure if this is actually the case).